# div not showing up?

Tags: html, css

For some reason, I can't get a `div` to display. When this happens, it's usually a stupid typo, but I searched for 10 minutes, rewrote the entire css file, and searched another 20 minutes, and I can't find anything like that. I've got a div that's centered, and another div inside that. The parent shows up fine, but the child inside it doesn't. Here's my CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#chartBox {
    width: 510px;
    height: 510px;
    background: #FFFF00;
    margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
}

#11 {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #000000;
}
```

And my HTML `body` (just `link` to css and `title` outside the `body`):

```
<body>
    <div id="chartBox">
        <div id="11">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

If I enter text in 11, the text shows up in the corner of chartBox, but the div's background and border don't show up.

Comment: While IDs starting with digits are valid in HTML5 (not in HTML4), they are not in CSS: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens (“-”), underscores (“_”), colons (“:”), and periods (“.”).

You can't use only numbers in div like "11". Rename it to "div11".

Comment: Does Rasmus Lerdorf have his PHP-ridden hands in CSS? What's the purpose of not allowing them to start with digits? Also, does this apply to classes?

Comment: @tkbx Yes, this applies to classes.

Comment: @tkbx: In many "languages" identifiers are not allowed to start with digits. This could be just to make parsing easier.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that, is some browsers do not support ids and classes starting with a number. Try `id="_11"` and `#_11 {` instead.